# How to fit the keyframes of an object into the new Frame Range, perfectly?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I want to edit the Frame Range in my scene from 0 - 2000 to 0 - 1000, that means I will have to resize the keyframes correspondingly to fit into that 1000 frames, so that the animations and movements don’t get stretched out.

***First question***, how do I do this, easily?

***Second question***, if the only way to do that is to resize the keyframes in Timeline, then here’s my problem, I intended to simply click an object to expose all keyframes of it in Timeline and then scale them, but, Timeline displays keyframes in a very limited way, to see the keyframes of a node, you have to click that node, but I keyframes literally everywhere, I can’t keep track of everything.
So, how do I click into an object and then see ALL keyframes that are attached to it, regardless of where the keyframe were assigned?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Dopesheet window instead of the Timeline, select all keyframes you need to scale, place the time cursor on the first keyframe and press S, 0.5, Enter.

Comment: Thank you! I've just found another of your relevant answer here (https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/290243/105546) which also helped a lot.